# Insert array of records into mysql with Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, bulkinsert, node-mysql, bulkloader

I have a array of data something like

```
var records = [
               {Name: '', Id: 1},
               {Name: '', Id: 2},
               {Name: '', Id: 3},
               {Name: '', Id: 4},
               {Name: '', Id: 5},
               {Name: '', Id: 6}
              ];
```

there could be thousands of items inside records array...

Ques1: Can we create a stored procedure which will accept an array of objects in mysql?

Ques2: Is there a way to bulk insert this data into mysql with Node JS?

Answer (score 7):

You can bulk insert the array of records ,but before that you might need to convert it into array of arrays

I use array reduce to get an array something like this

```
let j=[
               {Name: '', Id: 1},
               {Name: '', Id: 2},
               {Name: '', Id: 3},
               {Name: '', Id: 4},
               {Name: '', Id: 5},
               {Name: '', Id: 6}
              ];

              let values=j.reduce((o,a)=>{
                    let ini=[];
                    ini.push(a.Name);
                    ini.push(a.Id);
                    o.push(ini);
                    return o
              },[])
              console.log(values);
```

This will output

```
[["",1],["",2],["",3],["",4],["",5],["",6]]
```

Now inserting into the mysql database

> 1-Using normal callback

```
const con=require('./mysql.js'); //mysql connectionin mysql.js 

var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, id) VALUES ?";
con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) { //pass values array (from above)  directly here
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
  });
});
```

so the format of multiple data insert should be like `[[[a,b],[b,c],[d,k]]]`

> 2-Using promises

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");//for promises
const promisecon=Promise.promisifyAll(require('./mysql.js'));//
  var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, id) VALUES ?";
    promisecon.queryAsync(sql,[values]).then((result)=>{//bluebird identifies with Async
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      })
```

> 3-Using async await

```
 var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, id) VALUES ?";
async function build() {
            try {
              const result =await con.queryAsync(sql,[values]);

                 console.log(result);

            } catch (err) {
              // do something
            }
          }
          build();
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the list of insertIDs as result?

Comment: you mean the primary keys that are created after insertion? @MoeFar

Comment: Yup, I was looking for something like that