# nodejs not awaiting for async func to complete before returning results

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make a simple api with nodejs. However I can't get nodejs to wait for sql queries to finish.

How can I get nodejs to wait for the queries to finish? Am I using await/async wrong?

The goal here is to only return `d` after the queries have finished.

Database File

```
const DB_HOSTNAME = "localhost";
const DB_NAME = "testerino";
const DB_PORT = "8889";
const DB_USERNAME = "root";
const DB_PASSWORD = "root";

const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: DB_HOSTNAME,
  user: DB_USERNAME,
  password: DB_PASSWORD,
  database: DB_NAME,
  port: DB_PORT
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log("Connected to database");
});

async function query(sql){

  var results = await con.query(sql);
  console.log("foo completed")
  return results

}

module.exports = {
  con: con,
  query: query
}
```

userLogin File

```
const db = require('../../common/database');

function attemptUserLogin(usernameOrEmail, password){
  var d = {err: [], res: {}};

  console.log("attemptUserLogin");
  const foo = db.query("SELECT * FROM users");
  console.log("This should wait for foo to complete");

  return d;
}

module.exports = {
  attemptUserLogin: attemptUserLogin
};
```

Results

```
Connected to database
attemptUserLogin
This should wait for foo to complete
foo completed
```

^ it's not waiting

Comment: what is this function is trying to return, i cannot see you are expecting query results to be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `callback` with `await` .Make sure that your `con.query()` function returns `promise` ,to you to suceed in this.

```
async function query(sql){

      var results = await con.query(sql); // the result will be stored in results variable ,once the promise is resolved
    console.log(results) // the query result will be printed here
      return results // the result will be wrapped in promise and returned
    }
```

The above function will return result only when your promise is resolved and the returned data is stored in results variable.

Now if you want to use above function to get the data,you can do it in two ways

1-Use `then`.

```
query().then(data=>{
console.log(data) // this variable data holds the value you returned from above query function

})
```

2-Call the function with await (but you have to do it in async function)

```
async function other()
{
let query_result=await query(); // it will return the data from query function above
}
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387739/7849549) ,I have discussed all possible cases to query data.

Edit -The issue is with your  attemptUserLogin function,you have to make it async as well

```
async function attemptUserLogin(usernameOrEmail, password){
  var d = {err: [], res: {}};

  console.log("attemptUserLogin");
  const foo = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users"); // use await here
  console.log(foo);// result from query function above

  return d;
}
```

Comment: nice, okay that's returning a promise. Getting closer. How can I keep the function from returning before the promise is complete?

Comment: See the updated answer ,the query function won't return a result until the promise is resolved (await)

Comment: I gave it a try but I'm getting an error. ```async function query(sql){

  var results = await con.query(sql);

  return results
}

async function other(sql){
  let queryResult = await query(sql);

  return queryResult;
}```

Could you provide a full snipet of code to make sure I'm implementing this right?

Comment: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I think something isn't set right

Comment: Neither could I. I removed some things and tried something else. I updated the answer, is this what you were saying to do? It is still returning pending

Comment: I guess you are bit confused about how this async await thing works .You will get the data from the async query function i have used above ,see if you can console.log result in the query function i mentioned.

Comment: the above code ```async function query(sql){

      var results = await con.query(sql); // the result will be stored in results variable ,once the promise is resolved

      return results
    }``` returns a pending promise on my end. Should it be returning data?

Comment: Updated the answer please check.

Comment: I updated my question. It seems that `attemptUserLogin` is still proceeding even after `await`. I think I'll just drop nodejs all together and try php or golang for the backend.

Comment: I got your mistake ,wait I am updating my answer

Comment: Oh, super close now. It's returning in order and giving me back the completed object. I just don't know how to get the results out of the object

Comment: Do this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo))`.Please print the result you are getting if that doesn't works

Comment: Getting this error ```(node:29198) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Object.attemptUserLogin (/Users/trevorwood/Desktop/v-gitrepo/VCloudAdminPanelAPI/funcs/user/userLogin.js:11:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:29198) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: ```

Comment: Possibly there is some error with your query .What does console.log(foo) prints?

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM users``` it's just a simple query

Comment: what does console.log(foo) prints?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5az0w28q/ - added it here since it was too long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201713/discussion-between-shubh-and-trevor-wood).

Answer (score 1):

Revise your execute method like below and put `async/await` the way I did:

```
    // put async keyword here
const attemptUserLogin = async (usernameOrEmail, password) => {
    var d = {err: [], res: {}};

    console.log("attemptUserLogin");
    // Put await keyword here
    const foo = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users");
    console.log("This should wait foo.results: ",foo.results);

    return d;
}
```

Comment: It says I can't use await on db.query