# How to INSERT two tables at the same time and INSERT values received as an array

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have 2 tables a and b.

Two tables must be created at the same time, and table b has the forking key of table a.

Also, table b receives values as an array and multiple can be added at the same time.

1. Is there a more accurate method than SELECT/ORDER BY DESC/LIMIT 1 when inserting the created id of table a into the foreign key of table b?
2. I want to know how to receive the values of table b as an array and process them at once.
   The format received as req.body is as follows.(JSON)

```
"typeId": [1, 2, 3]
"figure": [90, 100, 50]
```

And this should be applied to the query like below.

```
INSERT INTO b(a_id, type_id, count)
VALUES
  (0, 1, 90),
  (0, 2, 100),
  (0, 3, 50);
```

Below is my current query.
DAO.js

```
const createData = async(user_id, a_data, a_id, type_id, count) => {
   await myDataSource.query(
     `INSERT INTO a (user_id, a_data)
   VALUES (?,?)`,
     [user_id, a_data]
   );

   const datas = await myDataSource.query(
     `INSERT INTO d(a_id, type_id, count)
   VALUES(?,?,?)`,
     [a_id, type_id, count]
   );
   return data;
};
```

I need help.

Comment: Perform both inserts in single transaction. All editions will be consistent - either all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

### Point 1

The way you are trying to get last id of inserted is wrong. That won't work  especially when you will have many users doing transaction same time.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2,...) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'...);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

[Check this solution to get the last inserted record id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query)

Above solution will give you inserted id record which you can use as foreign key for table b.

### Point 2

To insert multiple data once in a table, below is the way

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```

Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: 1. I proceeded in the way you told me, and it works fine. thank you
2. What I'm talking about is when you get the values as an array as body.
An example has been added to the body.

Comment: @ggyoE : Query is what you will need to prepare like I give solution in Point 2.

Comment: @ggyoE : [may be you are looking this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387739/1066828)